# How can I improve this?

Tags: shadows

I'm very newbie on Blender and also on design/ilustration, but on this quarantine I decided to learn it as a curiosity :)

I created this house from Midsommar, but I didn't like the result at all, it seems that it lacks some volume.

[image]

How do you think I could improve it and how to do it?
I thought about creating some shadow between the house and the green plane (ground) to create a separation, but I dont know how to do it...

Any help/tip, please?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to Blender SE! For the "seperation", try searching for ambient occlusion

Comment: Hello :). As @Jonas commented, enable AO in *Render Tab > Ambient Occlusion*. It will add shadows into corners and ridges.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to answer this question based on facts without involving personal opinions which is the goal on this platform, but let me try...

## Keep working on it

Well... it's a fact that it will get better eventually if you keep working on it. Many beginners have works that look very similar to what an experienced 3D artist would consider to be just a sketch or just a rough start and just stop working on them and that's how they fail to create an impressive image. So don't do that. Don't stop. Just keep working.

## Things to consider

Now it is also a fact that there are many things to consider when creating an interesting, aesthetically pleasing image. If I told you what to change it would be my opinion, but the existence of these things is a fact the way I see it. So here it goes, some of them are:

- The context. Why are you making it? Who will see it? How? In what medium.
- The idea. What do you want to communicate with the image. What's the message if there is one. What mood should it form?..
- Composition. Balance or imbalance. Places of objects or visual elements in relation to each other, directions viewers eyes move or are guided when looking at it and so on...
- Focal point. What is the main subject. How you lead to it, separate it, make it special. Depth - whats background, foreground, layers of depth...
- Patterns and groups, detail, cognitive ease while looking at it, distribution of shapes and stuff like that. This is interesting: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qMH_J_vcoqE
- Color. Color theory... Don't even know where to begin here. Google maybe :)
- Lighting. We have the luxury of creating absoolutely any type of lighting in 3d. That's a very powerful tool.
- Framing. Point of view. That changes a lot as well. Whose eyes/camera are you looking through? What perspective? How high, low, straight, angled and so on...
- Style. Realistic? Stylized? Resembling something?
- Believability/realism. Is the scale of your objects real, are the proportions believable? Are they detailed enough to be recognizable?..

I am sure there are many more, but maybe that helps at least a bit to just think about these things or imagine variations of them...

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your proportions are off. The well should be bigger compared to the house

Then your composition could be better ( a quick google search on basic principles for compositions will help you
Finally, play with your materials and colors
The grass looks too glossy for grass, and the sky has this interesting color :)
Of course you should follow what you want to do, maybe in your context the floor is plastic, etc.
Have fun with blender !